# Explication d'une phrase qui est trop longue

Tags: sens, littérature

J'ai un extrait ci-dessous qui me rend assez perdu. C'est une seule phrase qui fonctionne comme un paragraphe entier au début du livre *Le mystère de la chambre jaune* :

> J'imagine même que le public n'aurait jamais connu toute la vérité sur la prodigieuse affaire dite de la "Chambre Jaune", génératrice de tant de mystérieux et cruels et sensationnels drames, et à laquelle mon ami fut si intimement mêlé, si, à propos de la nomination récente de l'illustre Stangerson au grade de grand- croix de la Légion d'honneur, un journal du soir, dans un article misérable d'ignorance ou d'audacieuse perfidie, n'avait ressuscité une terrible aventure que Joseph Rouletabille eût voulu savoir, me disait-il, oubliée pour toujours.

Je comprends presque toute la phrase, mais que veut dire ceci ?

> n'avait ressuscité une terrible aventure que Joseph Rouletabille eût voulu savoir, me disait-il, oubliée pour toujours.

Je me trouve incapable d'identifier le sujet auquel la locution verbale « avait ressuscité » est liée. C'est quoi qui « n'avait ressuscité ... » ? La Légion d'honneur ? La vérité ? Stangerson ? Quelque chose/un d'autre ?

Merci en avance pour votre assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le sujet est le **journal du soir**. Si l'on supprime les parties de la phrase qui ne font qu'apporter des détails, cela donne :

> J'imagine même que le public n'aurait jamais connu toute la vérité sur la prodigieuse affaire dite de la "Chambre Jaune" si un journal du soir n'avait ressuscité une terrible aventure que Joseph Rouletabille eût voulu savoir oubliée pour toujours.

Le sens de la phrase est que le journal du soir a parlé d'une affaire très ancienne (=il l'a **ressuscitée**) que Joseph Roulebille espérait que tout le monde avait oubliée.